# Vertx - Concrete gradle/maven example with specific configuration

Tags: java, rest, gradle, microservices, vert.x

I am currently struggling to get the vertx-jersey (v3) working, I would like to have this:

```
Vertx 3
Jersey - Jackson
RxJava
HK2 DI
SQL-Client ( Postgresql )
```

Here you can find a representation of my needs:

```
@Inject
private TestDependency testDependency

@GET
@Path("async")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getJsonAsync(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse, @Context Vertx vertx) {
vertx.runOnContext(aVoid -> {
    MyObject o = new MyObject();
    o.setName("Andy");
    System.out.println(testDependency.getMessage());
    // some RxJava stuffs with Observable
    // some Postgresql client query with HSQLDB ( for test )
    asyncResponse.resume(o);
});
return response;
```

}

And for the runner:

```
DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions();
    // options.setIsolationGroup("A");
    options.setConfig(jerseyConfig);
    vertx.deployVerticle("java-hk2:" + JerseyVerticle.class.getCanonicalName(), options);
```

I got a lot of problems with HK2 like:
vertx org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException..

If someone can make a quick example with all of this working, it will be just great and useful.